# how to get the complete xpath for an web element using ruby capybara.Please advise

Tags: ruby, capybara

I tried getting via inspect-> copyxpath. But I did not get the full xpath.
Then i tried with the code

```
 findXpath=page.find('label', '$12,420.94', :match => :prefer_exact).path
```

But i got the message unable to locate the element $12,420.94.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

There is no version of find in Capybara that takes two strings as parameters.  If using Capybara < 2.7.0 you can do

```
page.find('label', text: '$12,420.94', :match => :prefer_exact)
```

which is a find using the default selector type (:css) for a 'label' element containing text of '$12,420.94'.  If using Capybara 2.7.0+ you can do

```
page.find(:label, '$12,420.94', :match => :prefer_exact)
```

which is basically the same thing, but using the :label selector type which was added to Capybara